# Change Button when Audio is finished Android

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player

I am making an app with Android Studio and I have an mp3 file in my app. I have added a play and pause button in it but my problem is that when I click on the play button, the pause button shows, but when an mp3 file finishes playing there is still a pause button display. I want it to change to the play button again automatically when the audio is finished. This is my code:

```java
  play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                length = mp.getCurrentPosition();


            } else {

                mp.seekTo((int) length);
                mp.start();
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use setOnCompletionListener;

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        // Do something when media player end playing
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using one button try creating two - Play and Pause...(I assume you are already using `Relativelayout`) and then use `pause.setVisibility(View.GONE)` & `play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`